# Vue warn: Unknown custom element: <education-item> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to fix the following error from a component, but it's still failing. The error is the following:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element "education-item": - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

In my password component, following script, I have the following:

```
<template>
<b-list-group class="education-list">
        <b-list-group-item
          class="align-items-start"
          v-for="(education, i) in educations"
          is="education-item"
          :key="i"
          :institute="education.institute"
          :major="education.major"
          :from="education.from"
          :to="education.to"
          @click:edit="education.splice(_id, 1)"
        >
          <div class="row" id="edu-item">
            <div class="eduimg col-md-2 pl-2 pt-2">
              <span class="dot"></span>
              <img class="dot-line" src="../../assets/line.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 pl-0 pr-0">
              <div class="eduinfo" id="eduinfo">
                <h6 class="institute font-weight-bold mt-2 mb-0">{{ education.major }}</h6>
                <p class="mb-0">{{ education.institute }}</p>
                <p class="mb-3">{{ education.from + " - " + education.to }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </b-list-group-item>

</template>

<script>
import AddEducationForm from "@/components/form/AddEducationForm";
import MainButton from "@/components/common/ui/main-button";

export default {
  name: "my-education",
  components: {
    AddEducationForm,
    MainButton,
  },
  props: {
    education: Object

  },
  data() {
    return {
      modal: false,
      isLoading: false,
      isEditing: false
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    isOwnProfile() {
      return this.profile.user._id === this.$store.getters.loggedInUser._id;
    },

    educations() {
      return this.$store.getters.profile.education;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The problem is that the vue component is not loading when the page opens, and the error disappears on refresh.

Can someone help me on how I fix up? I would appreciate if someone could guide me about this issue.

Comment: Is your intention for `education-item` to be locally registered or globally registered?

Comment: You would either need to import the missing component and then reference it in the components section or register it globally or import it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Add an import statement just inside your `<script>` tag like this:

```
import EducationItem from 'wherever/your/component/is';
```

And then add it to your components definition like this:

```
 components: {
    AddEducationForm,
    MainButton,
    EducationItem
  },
```